# Attempting to delete data from table1 into table2

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table of records, table 1.

I want to do 2 things, delete all records in table 1 from a specific user and add those deleted records to table2, as a back up.
I'm using mysqli prepared statements.
I also want to do it with one statement and not multiple statements, if possible.

My research led me to this

```
$stmt2 = $c1->prepare("DELETE FROM `scroll` OUTPUT.* INTO `deletedscroll` WHERE user= ? ");
```

But I keep getting syntax errors. This code may not be for mysqli is my guess, but the mysqli documentation doesn't go into this.

Does anyone know the correct syntax? I also see stuff on using:

```
DELETE FROM [source]
OUTPUT [deleted].<column_list>
INTO [destination] (<column_list>)
```

But I can not get that to work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotten this to work, which uses 2 calls, but it gets the job done without errors.

```
$stmt2 = $c1->prepare("INSERT INTO `deletedscroll` (user, text, flag,    date ) SELECT user, text, flag, date FROM `scroll` WHERE user= ? ");
$stmt2->bind_param('s', $user);
$stmt2->execute();
$stmt2->close();

//move deleted users records from scrolls to deleted table
$stmt3 = $c1->prepare("DELETE FROM `scroll` WHERE user= ? ");
$stmt3->bind_param('s', $user);
$stmt3->execute();
$stmt3->close();
```

Comment: Beware that unless you wrap this in a transaction (or otherwise lock the data in question), you may lose rows. If a record gets created between when the first statement and the second statement run, it will get deleted but not copied.

Comment: Good advice. But I belive I'm safe from this since it's a user app. Meaning queries are built to only run on the logged in user. This code only runs when user is deleting his/her account, so it is not possible that they will at the same time be adding a record.  Thanks.